# How do I hide the ScrollView scrollbar faster than the default?

Tags: java, android

How do I change the delay before the scrollbar on a ScrollView is hidden? I want it to hide instantly after scrolling. I tried android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="0" but it still sticks around and i have to either wait for it to disappear or click twice to click a button inside the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to set `android:scrollbarFadeDuration` to 0. Please report back whether this does the trick.

Comment: This has apparently had no effect. I still have to tap twice on any button to activate it or text box to give it focus.